# Film coordinate to world coordinate

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, 3d, computer-vision

I am working on building 3D point cloud from features matching using OpenCV3.1 and OpenGL.

I have implemented 1) Camera Calibration (Hence I am having Intrinsic Matrix of the camera) 2) Feature extraction( Hence I have 2D points in Pixel Coordinates).
I was going through few websites but generally all have suggested the flow for converting 3D object points to pixel points but I am doing completely backword projection. Here is the [ppt](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rtc12/CSE486/lecture12_6pp.pdf) that explains it well.

I have implemented film coordinates(u,v) from pixel coordinates(x,y)(With the help of intrisic matrix). Can anyone shed the light on how I can render "Z" of camera coordinate(X,Y,Z) from the film coordinate(x,y).

Please guide me on how I can utilize functions for the desired goal in OpenCV like solvePnP, recoverPose, findFundamentalMat, findEssentialMat.

Comment: Read the function definitions at openCv [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#Mat findFundamentalMat(InputArray points1, InputArray points2, int method, double param1, double param2, OutputArray mask)). This is to comprehend. For ex to calculate fundamental matrix all you need to do is to supply matching  pixel coordinated in two images.

Comment: Okk...can you please explain how can I reconstruct 3d points from pixel points? I have seen the documentation but can u elaborate step wise that how can I utilize those functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single camera and rotating object on fixed rotation platform I would implement something like this:

[image: setup]

Each camera has resolution `xs,ys` and field of view **FOV** defined by two angles **FOVx,FOVy** so either check your camera data sheet or measure it. From that and perpendicular distance (`z`) you can convert any pixel position (`x,y`) to 3D coordinate relative to camera (x',y',z'). So first convert pixel position to angles:

```
ax = (x - (xs/2)) * FOVx / xs 
ay = (y - (ys/2)) * FOVy / ys
```

and then compute cartesian position in 3D:

```
x' = distance * tan(ax)
y' = distance * tan(ay)
z' = distance
```

That is nice but on common image we do not know the `distance`. Luckily on such setup if we turn our object than any convex edge will make an maximum `ax` angle on the sides if crossing the perpendicular plane to camera. So check few frames and if maximal `ax` detected you can assume its an edge (or convex bump) of object positioned at `distance`.

If you also know the rotation angle `ang` of your platform (relative to your camera) Then you can compute the **un-rotated position** by using [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions) formula around y axis (`Ay` matrix in the link) and known platform center position relative to camera (just subbstraction befor the un-rotation)... As I mention all this is just simple geometry.

In an nutshell:

1. **obtain calibration data**

   FOVx,FOVy,xs,ys,distance. Some camera datasheets have only FOVx but if the pixels are rectangular you can compute the FOVy from resolution as

   ```
   FOVx/FOVy = xs/ys
   ```

   Beware with Multi resolution camera modes the FOV can be different for each resolution !!!
2. **extract the silhouette of your object in the video for each frame**

   you can subbstract the background image to ease up the detection
3. **obtain platform angle for each frame**

   so either use **IRC** data or place known markers on the rotation disc and detect/interpolate...
4. **detect `ax` maximum**

   just inspect the x coordinate of the silhouette (for each `y` line of image separately) and if peak detected add its **3D** position to your model. Let assume rotating rectangular box. Some of its frames could look like this:

   [image: max ax]

   So inspect one horizontal line on all frames and found the maximal `ax`. To improve accuracy you can do a close loop regulation loop by turning the platform until peak is found "exactly". Do this for all horizontal lines separately.

   **btw.** if you detect no `ax` change over few frames that means circular shape with the same radius ... so you can handle each of such frame as `ax` maximum.

Easy as pie resulting in 3D point cloud. Which you can sort by platform angle to ease up conversion to mesh ... That angle can be also used as texture coordinate ...

But do not forget that you will lose some concave details that are hidden in the silhouette !!!

If this approach is not enough you can use this same setup for **stereoscopic 3D reconstruction**. Because each rotation behaves as new (known) camera position.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help. your explanation is easy to understand and it's really helpful. I got some sample code which is implemented as same your explanation. Do you have any method to obtain calibration data except chess board pattern? Can I use some sphere(Rolling Ball) for calibration? if yes then How?

Comment: @ChiragBhuva if you place perfect cylinder on your platform and rotate the mid between max ax from left and right will give you rotation axis I think that is all you need to know .... The distance can be measured by showing some reference ball on the platform ... you can estimate the size from the pixel size ... no need to know the depth you just need to know the ratio between pixels and size along the plane perpendicular to camera and going through center of rotation (so place the ball on the center of platform) and compute x and y scales ...

Comment: Thanks for your all help. Can you share your email id so I can share more issue with you?

Comment: @ChiragBhuva why not add it here if related to this (it might help others too). If not related you can ask new question about it (and comment here with its link to notify me)....

Answer (score 2):

You can't, if all you have is 2D images from that single camera location.

In theory you could use heuristics to infer a Z stacking. But mathematically your problem is under defined and there's literally infinitely many different Z coordinates that would evaluate your constraints. You have to supply some extra information. For example you could move your camera around over several frames (Google "structure from motion") or you could use multiple cameras or use a camera that has a depth sensor and gives you complete XYZ tuples (Kinect or similar).

#### Update due to comment:

For every pixel in a 2D image there is an infinite number of points that is projected to it. The technical term for that is called *a ray*. If you have two 2D images of about the same volume of space each image's set of ray (one for each pixel) intersects with the set of rays corresponding to the other image. Which is to say, that if you determine the ray for a pixel in image #1 this maps to a line of pixels covered by that ray in image #2. Selecting a particular pixel along that line in image #2 will give you the XYZ tuple for that point.

Since you're rotating the object by a certain angle `θ` along a certain axis `a` between images, you actually have a lot of images to work with. All you have to do is deriving the camera location by an additional transformation (`inverse(translate(-a)·rotate(θ)·translate(a)`).

Then do the following: Select a image to start with. For the particular pixel you're interested in determine the ray it corresponds to. For that simply assume two Z values for the pixel. 0 and 1 work just fine. Transform them back into the space of your object, then project them into the view space of the next camera you chose to use; the result will be two points in the image plane (possibly outside the limits of the actual image, but that's not a problem). These two points define a line within that second image. Find the pixel along that line that matches the pixel on the first image you selected and project that back into the space as done with the first image. Due to numerical round-off errors you're not going to get a perfect intersection of the rays in 3D space, so find the point where the ray are the closest with each other (this involves solving a quadratic polynomial, which is trivial).

To select which pixel you want to match between images you can use some feature motion tracking algorithm, as used in video compression or similar. The basic idea is, that for every pixel a correlation of its surroundings is performed with the same region in the previous image. Where the correlation peaks is, where it likely was moved from into.

With this pixel tracking in place you can then derive the structure of the object. This is essentially what structure from motion does.

Comment: we can't use kinect but we are using single camera and will be capturing images of object by rotating object around 360 degree. so we have  collection of 2d images.
1)can you please guide us how can we find depth information(Z) from 2d images?

Comment: you can't find the exact value of Z(depth) for each pixel present in image, You can only find Z of all planar features, provided on extra information like length of any feature.

Comment: @datenwolf.......sir we have used AKAZE for feature matching and we have list of points matched between 2 images....can you please explain further about recovering cameraPose and Triangulation of this matched points?

Comment: @ChiragBhuva: I explained it all in my answer update.

Comment: @datenwolf.....sir i am sorry but i am beginner in computer vision and opencv....i have attached my code till recover pose...i am sure you can guide us on it... 
Link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10AhbPNrPIoQ77YSEHloZiK9x4v67xAOn5LV5Py8CzGg

Comment: @ChiragBhuva if you can place your camera so it is aligned perpendicularly to rotation axis and in known distance to it you can do silhouette extraction. With rotation angle info (obtained by markers or sensor) you can use simple geometry to do the 3D surface extraction. But you will lose some concave details that are hidden in the silhouette.

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the response. Theoretically, it sounds good, can you elaborate more? what exactly I need to do? if possible please spread some light on the same using some samples or any research paper.

Comment: @ChiragBhuva OK I will try to make an answer for you  tomorrow its too late  and hot today for such thinking ...

Comment: @Spektre yaa it's ok you can take your time.