# 3d point cloud of an object using Kinect

Tags: c++, opengl, kinect, point-clouds, kinect-sdk

I've got a point cloud of an object using kinect and I want to create a 3d representation of the point cloud and save the image. I'm not sure how I can approach this task. I want it to be able to detect an object and derive the point cloud of the object. For example for 3d scanning purposes, it would be able to 3d scan the object from all directions and then get a point cloud from it.

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
#include "glut.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Ole2.h>

#include <NuiApi.h>
#include <NuiImageCamera.h>
#include <NuiSensor.h>

// OpenGL Variables
long depthToRgbMap[width*height*2];
// We'll be using buffer objects to store the kinect point cloud
GLuint vboId;
GLuint cboId;

// Kinect variables
HANDLE depthStream;
HANDLE rgbStream;
INuiSensor* sensor;

bool initKinect() {
    // Get a working kinect sensor
    int numSensors;
    if (NuiGetSensorCount(&numSensors) < 0 || numSensors < 1) return false;
    if (NuiCreateSensorByIndex(0, &sensor) < 0) return false;

    // Initialize sensor
    sensor->NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_DEPTH | NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH, // Depth camera or rgb camera?
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,                // Image resolution
        0,        // Image stream flags, e.g. near mode
        2,        // Number of frames to buffer
        NULL,     // Event handle
        &depthStream);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamOpen(NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR, // Depth camera or rgb camera?
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,                // Image resolution
        0,      // Image stream flags, e.g. near mode
        2,      // Number of frames to buffer
        NULL,   // Event handle
        &rgbStream);
    return sensor;
}

void getDepthData(GLubyte* dest) {
    float* fdest = (float*) dest;
    long* depth2rgb = (long*) depthToRgbMap;
    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
    if (sensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(depthStream, 0, &imageFrame) < 0) return;
    INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
    texture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);
    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0) {
        const USHORT* curr = (const USHORT*) LockedRect.pBits;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
                // Get depth of pixel in millimeters
                USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*curr++);
                // Store coordinates of the point corresponding to this pixel
                Vector4 pos = NuiTransformDepthImageToSkeleton(i, j, depth<<3, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480);
                *fdest++ = pos.x/pos.w;
                *fdest++ = pos.y/pos.w;
                *fdest++ = pos.z/pos.w;
                // Store the index into the color array corresponding to this pixel
                NuiImageGetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixelAtResolution(
                    NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480, NULL,
                    i, j, depth<<3, depth2rgb, depth2rgb+1);
                depth2rgb += 2;
            }
        }
    }
    texture->UnlockRect(0);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(depthStream, &imageFrame);
}

void getRgbData(GLubyte* dest) {
    float* fdest = (float*) dest;
    long* depth2rgb = (long*) depthToRgbMap;
    NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
    NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
    if (sensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(rgbStream, 0, &imageFrame) < 0) return;
    INuiFrameTexture* texture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
    texture->LockRect(0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0);
    if (LockedRect.Pitch != 0) {
        const BYTE* start = (const BYTE*) LockedRect.pBits;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
                // Determine rgb color for each depth pixel
                long x = *depth2rgb++;
                long y = *depth2rgb++;
                // If out of bounds, then don't color it at all
                if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > width || y > height) {
                    for (int n = 0; n < 3; ++n) *(fdest++) = 0.0f;
                }
                else {
                    const BYTE* curr = start + (x + width*y)*4;
                    for (int n = 0; n < 3; ++n) *(fdest++) = curr[2-n]/255.0f;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    texture->UnlockRect(0);
    sensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame(rgbStream, &imageFrame);
}

void getKinectData() {
    GLubyte* ptr;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    ptr = (GLubyte*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    if (ptr) {
        getDepthData(ptr);
    }
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
    ptr = (GLubyte*) glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    if (ptr) {
        getRgbData(ptr);
    }
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
}

void rotateCamera() {
    static double angle = 0.;
    static double radius = 3.;
    double x = radius*sin(angle);
    double z = radius*(1-cos(angle)) - radius/2;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(x,0,z,0,0,radius/2,0,1,0);
    angle += 0.05;
}

void drawKinectData() {
    getKinectData();
    rotateCamera();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);

    glPointSize(1.f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, width*height);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (!init(argc, argv)) return 1;
    if (!initKinect()) return 1;

    // OpenGL setup
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);

    // Set up array buffers
    const int dataSize = width*height * 3 * 4;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cboId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cboId);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, dataSize, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // Camera setup
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, width /(GLdouble) height, 0.1, 1000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0);

    // Main loop
    execute();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kinect will give you  just point cloud (PCL) of static object surface visible to it. If you want the whole object you need to combine more views covering its whole surface either by moving/rotating the object or Kinect itself or using more Kinects. The problem is that for combining all the PCLs must be in the same reference frame so you need to know relative position between object and Kinect for each view. That part is hard without additional sensors and stuff but possible. As you did not specify any details on this we can only guess making this unanswerable as too broad

Comment: You should add more details on the scanning process and where exactly are you stuck.... also google stuff like **structure from motion** , **SIFT/SURF** , **RANSAC** or use aditional HW like [rotary platform](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51607638/2521214) etc ... PS detecting objects with Kinect is easy as the depth is not continous on the boundaries ... The rest is similar to panoramatic stitching hence the keywords I suggested ... Also markers can help a lot with the reference frame identification